# Does "for it" mean "for a while" in some cases?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/w6mdjf4nVTA?t=133)

> Initially the gradient is positive
>   and fairly constant, but `for it` drops to
>   zero at the peak, it then becomes
>   negative for a period before returning
>   to zero.

[m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20it) gives 2 meanings about `for it`

> certain to be punished

and

> in favor of the thing specified

neither of them seem to be the case.

Does "for it" mean "for a while" in this case?

Comment: Is this from a recording? Could you link us to the recording or a snippet so we can hear it? That sentence reads really weirdly and I wouldn't expect a native speaker to say it.

Comment: @GlennWillen updated. Thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase “but for” [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but%20for) “except for”:

> ...positive and fairly constant, *except* for it drops to zero at the peak...

The lecturer could have said this more clearly.

Comment: This answer is correct, but It would be better if you provided a [reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but%20for). Also note that the complete sentence quoted is quite awkward. It should really be *but for it **dropping** to zero at the peak, **and** it then . . .*

Comment: It should *really* be phrased completely differently. Changing "drops" to "dropping" and inserting "and" is putting a band-aid on it. There are three local extremes on the graph where the slope of the tangent line is zero, and approach zero smoothly. "Positive and fairly constant" is inaccurate, as is saying that the peak is an exception to this, since the premise is false, and since slopes get closer and closer to zero near the local maximum.